# Interface hierarchy: general purpouse and how to use it

Tags: java, interface, hierarchy

I have two interfaces and one class. This is what I have:

```
public interface InterfaceA { ... }
public interface InterfaceB extends { ... }
public class MyClass implements InterfaceB { ... }
```

I have few questions:

1. Why `InterfaceB` cannot implement `InterfaceA`?
2. Why `MyClass` can leave `InterfaceA`'s methods unimplemented?
3. To sum up, what's the purpose of a structure like this one? When could it be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Why InterfaceB cannot implements InterfaceB?**

Because InterfaceB itself is an interface. Either you should extend InterfaceA or make InterfaceB concrete/abstract class.

**2. Why MyClass can leave InterfaceA's methods unimplemented?**

Really! If MyClass is not an abstract class, I don't think that's possible.

**3. To sum up, what's the purpuse of a structure like this one? When could it be useful?**

You can see Collection framework hierarchy, and you will get the idea.